making column wider in GridViewDataColumn of ASPxGridLookup ( Dev express)
I have used this part of the code
<dx:ASPxGridLookup  ID="wddlContoBancario" runat="server" SelectionMode="Single" ClientInstanceName="gridLookup"
  KeyFieldName="PROG_NUMERO_CONTO" TextFormatString="{2}" MultiTextSeparator=", " 
 CssClass="wddl"  ButtonStyle-CssClass="wddl-button">
 <Columns>
    <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowSelectCheckbox="True" />
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="NUMBER" Visible="false" />
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Currency" Caption="Currency" Settings-AllowAutoFilter="False" />
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn  FieldName="Name"  Caption="Bank Name" width="500px"  Settings-AllowAutoFilter="False" >
      
    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="IBAN"  Caption="IBAN"  Settings-AllowAutoFilter="False" />
 </Columns>
 
</dx:ASPxGridLookup>

The wide to the column  Bank name is not working and I can not make it wider

Seems OK and should work. Try removing CssClass="wddl" and check the result.
